# How to set Datepicker bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to create an entry date for a project. here I use the datepicker from bootstrap.

here my code :

```html
<input class="form-control tanggal" id="date" autocomplete="off" name="date_start" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" readonly="" required="">

<input class="form-control tanggal" autocomplete="off" id="date_end" name="date_end" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" readonly="" required="required">
```

and this my javascript :

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date_start"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    var currentdate = new Date();
    currentdate.setDate(currentdate.getDate() + 1);
    var tomorrow = currentdate.toJSON().slice(0,10);
    date_input.datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      container: container,
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: tomorrow
    })
  })
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date_end"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    var currentdate = new Date();
    currentdate.setDate(currentdate.getDate() + 1);
    var tomorrow = currentdate.toJSON().slice(0,10);
    date_input.datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      container: container,
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: tomorrow
    })
  })
</script>
```

my problem is how i can set my **date_end** is start from`+1 day` after **date_start** and cant select the day less than **date_start** ? have some one give me solution?

what code should I add? to make it work like what i want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adam Projo

I have checked your fiddle and implemented the below code and it works. Please provide `id="start_date"` for **date_start** and `id="end_date"` for **date_end**. Please have a look

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#start_date").datepicker({
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: true,
        }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()+1);
        $('#end_date').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
        });
    })
```

Comment: iam already try but its unfortunately not work [ https://fiddle.jshell.net/fmv7jbja/ ] or did i miss something ?

Comment: Adam pls try with updated answer. I think it will for you

Comment: ahh thats work now, and did 1 more how to set format date to YYY-MM-DD ? maybe  can help me

Comment: I have made a fiddle according to your required format. Please check it. https://jsfiddle.net/tfL2xmyf/2/ . If it works for you then mark it as correct answer so it will be helpful to others